# How do you attach to a Java applet with JavaSnoop?

Tags: java, debugging, hook

I am troubleshooting a poorly documented Java applet and would like to attach to it with JavaSnoop to actually see what arguments are being passed into certain method calls.  I can successfully attach to a locally run Java application in a jar file, but cannot get attachment to an applet to work.

I have been assuming you click "Attach & Snoop Process...", run the applet, and then should see that applet's process in the list.  I get nothing in this list when I run any applet.  Am I missing a step?

I am also open to alternative ways to hook the method call to read its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> ..alternative ways to hook the method call to read its arguments.

Extend the applet and method.  Embed the extended applet.  In the extended method, log the arguments.